# Change position of prenote when ibid (if statement in \DeclareCiteCommand)

Tags: biblatex, citing

The referencing guide that I follow requires the `prenote` to come after the 'Ibid' literal in cases where ibid is appropriate.

For example:

```
s 1 Really Awesome Statute.
s 3 Ibid demonstrates awesome stuff << wrong
Ibid s 3 demonstrates awesome stuff << correct
```

I am attempting to achieve this by altering the `footcite` command.

The command was originally defined as:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\bibsentence
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

I am attempting to use:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {
      \bibsentence
      \ifthenelse{\shoulddoibid}{%
      }{%    
          \usebibmacro{prenote}
      }
  }
  {
      \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
      \usebibmacro{cite}
  }
  {
      \multicitedelim
  }
  {
      \ifthenelse{\shoulddoibid}{%
        \usebibmacro{prenote}
      }{%
      }
      \usebibmacro{cite:postnote}
  }
```

with

```
\newcommand{\shoulddoibid}{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
```

However, this appears to completely break `footcite`:

- I get lots of `∆=∆` symbols (eg `Ibid ∆=∆, 293`)
- `Ibid` appears in the wrong place
- `prenote` and `cite:postnote` are replaced with `∆=∆` even where they are not defined

My guess is that my problem is with the definition of `shoulddoibid`, or with the `DeclareCiteCommand` (likely the latter).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could you add a minimal working example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/233#233) )? This would make it a lot easier to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that `\shoulddoibid` wasn't working.

I looked in the biblatex manual, and it turns out that `iffirsonpage` is context-dependent.

I think that the parser was evaluating it in the context of `\newcommand`, making it a literal, rather than evaluating it each time as expected.

I've added the final command in case anyone finds it useful.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {%
      \togglefalse{hasibid}%
      \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}{%
          \toggletrue{hasibid}%
      }{%    
          \bibsentence%
          \usebibmacro{prenote}%
      }%
  }%
  {%
      \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
      \usebibmacro{cite}%
  }%
  {%
      \multicitedelim%
  }%
  {%
      \iftoggle{hasibid}{%
        \usebibmacro{prenote}%
      }{%
      }%
      \usebibmacro{cite:postnote}%
  }
```